# by default it's blank I want first tab as default

Tags: javascript, css, tabs

as you can see when the page reloads the section under these tabs are empty (maybe using wrong word) need to click this to see content

All I want is when page the loads content on the first tab show by default

[Click Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs)

*hope you undersatnd me*

Comment: So you want first element to be selected by default?

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) isn't a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, I want first element to be selected by default. :D

Comment: _“hope you undersatnd me”_ – please go read [ask] first of all.

Comment: @HardikGupta kindly check the fixtures in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do these 2 things to achieve the desired result:

1.
Use `style="display:block;"` on the first tab  because the logic of your javascript code works like this.
So on page load the 1st tab content will alwyas be visible and on tab change it will work accordingly.

2. Add `class="tablinks active"` to the first tab link to make it active.

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>
   body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

   /* Style the tab */
   div.tab {
       overflow: hidden;
       border: 1px solid #ccc;
       background-color: #f1f1f1;
   }

   /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
   div.tab button {
       background-color: inherit;
       float: left;
       border: none;
       outline: none;
       cursor: pointer;
       padding: 14px 16px;
       transition: 0.3s;
       font-size: 17px;
   }

   /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
   div.tab button:hover {
       background-color: #ddd;
   }

   /* Create an active/current tablink class */
   div.tab button.active {
       background-color: #ccc;
   }

   /* Style the tab content */
   .tabcontent {
       display: none;
       padding: 6px 12px;
       border: 1px solid #ccc;
       border-top: none;
   }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>

   <p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

   <div class="tab">
     <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
     <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
     <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
   </div>

   <div id="London" class="tabcontent" style="display:block;">
     <h3>London</h3>
     <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
   </div>

   <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
     <h3>Paris</h3>
     <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
   </div>

   <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
     <h3>Tokyo</h3>
     <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
   </div>

   <script>
   function openCity(evt, cityName) {
       var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
       tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
       for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
           tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
       }
       tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
       for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
           tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
       }
       document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
       evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
   }
   </script>
        
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

All of your `.tabcontent` tabs have their `display` property set to `none`.  Change the display property of your first tab to `block` and it will show by default.

Comment: didn't work :( 
after changing `.tabcontent`'s `display` property from `none` to `block` everything is showing by default in first tab

Comment: Yes.  Not on all of them, just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this and then put this in script

```
$('.tablinks').eq(0).click();
```

[Working example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FF9H3KXP3ZCS)